# Why is my JSON formatting different from HighCharts examples?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, highcharts

When I use jQuery's $.GetJSON the result that is returned looks like this:

```
{"Points":[{"X":1,"Y":6},{"X":2,"Y":5},{"X":3,"Y":1},{"X":4,"Y":5},{"X":5,"Y":5},{"X":6,"Y":10},{"X":7,"Y":4},{"X":8,"Y":1},{"X":9,"Y":9},{"X":10,"Y":2}]}
```

However, the Highcharts documentation states the output should look like this:

```
[
[1,12],
[2,5],
[3,18],
[4,13],
[5,7],
[6,4],
[7,9],
[8,10],
[9,15],
[10,22]
]
```

How do I fix this?

Extra info: I am using this example
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#3

Here is my code:

JavaScript

```
<script>
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("/HighchartsTest/JSONTest", function (data) {
            options.series[0].data = data;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
</script>
```

MVC C#

```
public JsonResult JSONTest()
{
    return Json(new GenericInfo(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public class GenericInfo
{
    public Point[] Points { get; set; }

        public GenericInfo()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            Points = new Point[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < 10;)
            {
                Points[i] = new Point(++i, r.Next(0, 10) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

The chart that I'm getting is empty. When inspecting the chart with the console it seems like the `chart.series[0].data` array is empty. I can't seem to figure out if my code is wrong or if it's simply not accepting the JSON object.

Comment: Both are valid JSON. Have you tried using the JSON provided by jQuery's $.GetJSON?

Comment: Yes, the JSON that gets returned is the data I'm using for the chart, however the chart is empty.

Comment: Added extra information to the original post.

Comment: If you want your json to look like that then you need to return an `int[][]` rather than a `GenericInfo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was sending the GenericInfo object rather than the list Points itself. After this I also needed to change the names X,Y to x,y (non capitals), and this fixed the chart.